# using ngRoute breaks any controller-driven page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an application that uses a Router to load pages across a shared template, and other pages that are organized by Controllers, Services, and templates that run within the context of those controllers. It's a simple process to get the various entries of the Controllers and application to run within the same context, but when I have a set of ngRoute defined rules in place, the router stops working.

The routes I have in place are set in js/core/app.js and look like this:

```
var app = angular.module('ApplicationSystem', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'js/login/templates/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginController'
        })
        .when('/application', {
            templateUrl: 'js/application/templates/application.html',
            controller: 'ApplicationController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/login'
        });
    }
]);
```

And as an example, the Login application itself does not load. Only a blank page loads. The Actual application in reference is loaded via an ng-controller directive (ng-app is used in the parent template).

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="LoginController">
  <h2>Login</h2>
  <!-- Contents -->
</div>
```

The parent template (index.html by reference)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Application</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="settings.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/ngstorage/ngStorage.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/spin.js/spin.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/core/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/login/LoginController.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="masterwrapper" ng-app="ApplicationSystem">
      <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the aforementioned controller

```
var app = angular.module('ApplicationSystem', []);

app.controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $cookies, $location, $ngStorage) {

    console.log("Init LoginController");

    $scope.LogIn = function (username, password) {
      //Login service and factory calls here
    };

});
```

I'm not really clear on what the culprit could be here. If I can get the template to render again, that would at least get me back on track. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's means --> "ng-app is used in the parent template". Can you provide a complete DOM which start by <html></html>?
ng-controller isn't necessary because you configure controller in your route provider

Comment: I added a complete dom reference for the index page, with ng-app and ng-view directives as they appear in the source.

Comment: Have you got some errors in console ?

Comment: No error in console, but I have a console.log inside the app.js and LoginController.js (excluded from the code above), and only the one in app.js fires, at the first line. So it looks like the Controller isn't loading at all.

Comment: Keep ng-controller on DOM and delete controller: 'LoginController' from router configuration.
Ensure with dev console that you have a request to get login.html when your url is http://.../login
If the request is send: 
 - check the response correspond to your template
 - provide the DOM result (get it with chrome dev console).

Finally ensure, in network view of chrome dev console there is no 404 errors

Comment: According to the Chrome Network tab, it never makes any attempt to load the Login template. No HTTP request for it is ever made -- no 200, 404, 500. It never fires. So the issue is the router is being overwritten or never initialized. I've attempted to fire off the router using the url bar and with a hyperlink.

Comment: Last idea : Did you try to configure html5Mode like this $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); ?